# Broken CAPTCHA challenge?

Tags: bug

A minute or so ago, I attempted to post a question. This resulted in a pop-up (well, "lightbox" `div`) being drawn on the screen, with the following text in it (my emphasis):

> Human Verification
>
> Are you a human being? We apologize for the confusion, but we can't
>   quite tell if you're a person or a script. Please don't take this
>   personally. Bots and scripts can be remarkably lifelike these days!
>
> Check **the CAPTCHA box**, and we'll be out of your way.

My question is: what CAPTCHA box?

Answer (score 1):

That's your browser blocking Google's JavaScript. I hate it too, but it makes my job easier so I can't really say much against it.

Temporarily allow `https://[^/]google.com/.*` and `https://[^/]gstatic.com/.*` to enable the ReCAPTCHA. Make sure to save your question / answer first, in case the page refresh wipes it!

Comment: Thanks. May give that a go. However, I am no longer getting that pop-up when I click the "Post Your Question" button. Instead, the site now says, "You can only post once every 40 minutes." This is despite the fact that the last time I posted a question was ~57 minutes ago. Unfortunately, I can't report that here because the last question I posted *here* was posted <40 minutes ago.

Comment: @sampablokuper That's odd. I think that's an actual bug. Maybe it counted the ReCAPTCHA as an attempt.

Comment: @sampablokuper You haven't hit any custom rate limit ("No rate limit applied to this user"). If it's not gone by now, I suggest bringing this up on [meta.se].

Comment: [Done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321266/broken-timer-you-can-only-post-once-every-40-minutes), thanks.